# GoogleApiClientを使用したGeofenceはどのように実装するのですか？

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-service

はじめまして。
Androidの勉強を初めて１０ヶ月の初心者です。
Geofenceを取得するためAndroidStudioで勉強してきたのですが、情報（本、HP、サンプルコード）が少なく自己解決が難しいため、質問させていただきました。

質問：GoogleApiClientを使用したGeofenceはどのように実装するのですか？

実現したいことは、Geofence（場所は固定）に入ったらインテントを発行する。
だけなのですが、これまでの勉強方法が本や実際に動作するサンプルコードから読み解くようにしてきたため、それらがない状態でどのようにすればいいのか？で苦労しています。
調べたところ、これまで使用されていたライブラリがなくなりGoogleApiClientを使用することがわかり、Mapの表示、現在位置の取得まではできたのですが、どのようにGeofenceを組み込むのかがわかりません。
アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

参考サイト
http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-google-play-services-location-api-geofencing/
http://www.zionsoft.net/2014/11/google-play-services-locations-2/
その他多数。

サンプルコードを追加いたします。
各サイトを参考に作ったもので、動作は地図を表示させ、現在位置を習得、カメラを移動。
その際、ジオフェンス内ならLogに表示させることを目指したものですが、 `Geofencescheck()` の `addGeofences` の入力で失敗してしまいます。
また、 `onLocationChanged()` に `Geofencescheck()` を仕込んだため、毎回、位置チェックで確認するようにしたのですが、これがジオフェンスを使用する場合の正しいのか？も判断できていません。
この部分のアドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private final MainActivity self = this;
    private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    private GoogleMap mMap = null;
    private GoogleApiClient locationClient = null;
    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(5000)
            .setFastestInterval(16)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
    ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if(mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        locationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)        //利用するAPIの指定
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)        //接続完了リスナ
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this) //接続失敗リスナ
                .build();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d("mLocationClient", "接続");
        super.onStart();

        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d("mLocationClient", "接続解除");
        locationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.d("onNewIntent", String.valueOf(intent));
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        int transitionType = event.getGeofenceTransition();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        CameraPosition cameraPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())).zoom(17.0f)
                .bearing(0).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPos));

        //①ここにGeofenceの生成登録
        Geofencescheck();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result){
        Toast.makeText(self, "onConnectionFailed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        addGeofence();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint){
        fusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(locationClient, REQUEST, this);
        Toast.makeText(self, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause){

    }


    private void addGeofence() {
        // Geofence の作成 　テスト：関西国際空港
        // 緯度
        double latitude = 34.436346;
        // 経度
        double longitude = 135.244140;
        // 半径(メートル)
        float radius = 1000;

        //Geofenceの作成
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("ID")
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, radius)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .build());


        // PendingIntent の生成
        Intent intent = new Intent(self, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }


    private void Geofencescheck(){
        try {
            // Geofences の登録
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(locationClient, mGeofenceList, pendingIntent);
            Log.d("addGeofences", "addGeofences成功");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("addGeofences", "addGeofences失敗");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
お恥ずかしい話ですが実は、教えていただいたサイトは全て調べており、その結果、何が答えなのか？と混乱してしまい、ご質問した次第です。
参考に記して頂いたコードも単体では理解しているのですが、例えば、自分の現在位置を地図に表示するコードの中にどのように入れればいいのか？　 implementsにConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListenerか、または、GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListenerを使用すべきか？も理解できない状態です。
多分、locationClient（現在位置）、mGeofenceList（ジオフェンス位置）
pendingIntent（インテント発行場所）をaddGeofencesに登録、判定？して「古いですが日本語はこちら」のコードのようにonNewIntent（）で受け取れると考えているのですが、自作コードを実行するとaddGeofencesで不具合が起こり接続不良→再接続で無限ループに陥ってしまう次第です。
現在コードを改造して余分なコードが入っているためすぐにこちらに挙げれません。
お手数をお掛けしますが、もう少し具体的な実装方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: 自己解決出来ましたのでご報告します。
　原因はジオフェンスのコードではなく、onNewIntent（​）にありました。
AndroidManifestにandroid:launchMode="singleTask"を記載していなかったことが原因です。
　Shintaro氏のアドバイスのお陰で、ジオフェンス以外をチェックすることに気をまわすことができたためと思います。
　ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeofencingApiはこちら
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html

Geofence.Builderはこちら
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html

wearableですがgeofenceの実装はこちら
https://developer.android.com/samples/Geofencing/Application/src/com.example.android.wearable.geofencing/MainActivity.html#l95

古いですが日本語はこちら
http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-google-play-services-location-api-geofencing/

---

## 追記：

現在地取得もそうですが、ジオフェンスにしてもGoogleApiClientをのインスタンスを作った時などにコールバックが設定され、現在地が動いた時やジオフェンスだったら領域に入ったなどのイベント発生時にonLocationChangedやインテントがでます。ゆえに提示いただいたGeofencescheck()のようなことはしなくてもイベントは出ますし、Geofencescheck()で現在地変更ごとに「領域に入った」かどうかチェックするならGeofencesは入りません。
あと、本論とずれますがtry～catchの使い方（文法ではなくて）も違います。
詳しく回答しようとすると、量が多いので時間がかかります。（具体例も出せてませんが・・）

他の方の回答を待つか、「インターフェース」「コールバック」「implements」について調べると解決するかもしれません。

---

上記を参考にしてこんなかんじはどうでしょうか。

```
//GoogleApiClientの作成
locationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
         .addApi(LocationServices.API)
         .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
         .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
         .build();

// PendingIntent の生成
Intent intent = new Intent(context, 伝えるactivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//Geofenceの作成
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
        .setRequestId("ID")
        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
        .setCircularRegion(緯度, 経度, 半径メートル)
        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
        .build());

//GeofencingApiに加える
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(locationClient,mGeofenceList,
        pendingIntent);
```

Comment: コメント出来ないのでこちらに。
基本的に現在地取得と同じでGoogle API clientをconnect()した後、onConnectedなど各種インターフェースを実装し、現在地取得だったらonLocationChangeやgetLastLocationで取得しているところを、通知先のonNewIntentで受け取るといいと思います。
具体例はいろいろ考えられますが、ポッと出ないのでお待ちください・・

Comment: コメント出来ないのでこちらに。
追記しました

Comment: お忙しい中、ご回答をいただきありがとうございます。
ご指摘された部分をご説明させていただくと、まず、従来はGeofencescheck()を設定せず「古いですが日本語はこちら」のコードのようにaddGeofence()内に記載しておりました。
この場合、ご説明させて頂いているようにジオフェンス内に入っている時「エラーの無限ループが発生」しておりましたので、テスト用に分離させ各状態で同状態になるか？を確認したため、このような構造になっております。他に参考にしたサンプルにもこの構造が見られたため、有効かな？と期待したのですが、あまり意味がなかったようですね。
try～catchに関してはあまり深く理解しておらず、何らかの入力に対して例外（エラー）を回避するものと思っておりました。
「インターフェース」「コールバック」「implements」を調べると共に、他の方の回答を待ってみたいと思います。